# SQL Function of Address Lines

Tags: sql, function, concatenation

HI I trying to extend one of our built in function that concatenates addressline 1 and 2. I am try to extend this logic to Addressline 1,2,3 and 4. The sample of built-in function is here below. My brain stopped working after three lines. i would greatly appreciate if you guys could help me on this. thanks

```
CREATE function [dbo].[UFN_CONCATENATEADDRESSLINES]
(
  @ADDRESSLINE1 nvarchar(max),
  @ADDRESSLINE2 nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
  begin
    declare @ADDRESSBLOCK nvarchar(max);

    set @ADDRESSBLOCK = 
      case when (@ADDRESSLINE1 is null and @ADDRESSLINE2 is null)
           then null
           when (@ADDRESSLINE1 is not null and @ADDRESSLINE2 is null)
           then
              case when len(ltrim(rtrim(@ADDRESSLINE1))) > 0
                   then @ADDRESSLINE1
                   else null end
           when (@ADDRESSLINE1 is null and @ADDRESSLINE2 is not null)
           then
              case when len(ltrim(rtrim(@ADDRESSLINE2))) > 0
                   then @ADDRESSLINE2
                   else null end
           else -- (@ADDRESSLINE1 is not null and @ADDRESSLINE2 is not null)
              case when len(ltrim(rtrim(@ADDRESSLINE1))) > 0 and len(ltrim(rtrim(@ADDRESSLINE2))) = 0
                   then @ADDRESSLINE1
                   when len(ltrim(rtrim(@ADDRESSLINE1))) = 0 and len(ltrim(rtrim(@ADDRESSLINE2))) > 0
                   then @ADDRESSLINE2
                   else (@ADDRESSLINE1 + char(13) + char(10) + @ADDRESSLINE2) end
           end;

    return @ADDRESSBLOCK;
  end
```

The Matrix with action I have built for the new extended function is like below.

```
Add1    |Add2    | Add3  |Add4   |Action
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filled  |Filled  |Filled |Filled |Bring all columns as address block
Filled  |Filled  |Filled |NULL   |Bring first 3 as address block
Filled  |Filled  |NULL   |NULL   |Bring first 2 as address block
Filled  |NULL    |NULL   |NULL   |Bring only 1 as address block
NULL    |NULL    |NULL   |NULL   |Mark it as null
NULL    |NULL    |NULL   |Filled |Move 4 to 1
NULL    |NULL    |Filled |Filled |Move 3 and 4 to 1 and 2 respectively
NULL    |Filled  |Filled |Filled |Move 2 to 1, 3 to 2 and 4 to 3
Filled  |Filled  |NULL   |Filled |Move 4 to 3
Filled  |NULL    |NULL   |Filled |Move 4 to 2
Filled  |NULL    |Filled |Filled |Move 3 and 4 to 2 and 3
```

Comment: not sure why the table i posted is displayed in line here. :-)

Comment: Which database are you using? Different databases enable different solutions

Comment: Hi Allan , I am using SQL server 2008 r2

Comment: Two of the rows in your table look a little questionable - are there really certain circumstances (only `Add4` filled, and `1,2 and 4` filled, where you actually want to remove some data?

Comment: Hi Damien thanks for spoting that. For this line 
Filled  |Filled  |NULL   |Filled |Move 4 to 2
The Action should Move 4 to 3.

Comment: If you want to, you can edit your question and correct the table. The edit link is at the bottom left of the question, just below the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function does what you want. It does this in a uniform manner though, rather than following the slightly odd spec that you have for certain rows in your table:

```
create function dbo.CompressAddress (
    @AddressLine1 nvarchar(max),
    @AddressLine2 nvarchar(max),
    @AddressLine3 nvarchar(max),
    @AddressLine4 nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
return
    NULLIF(COALESCE(CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(@AddressLine1))>0 THEN
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(@AddressLine1)) END + char(13) + char(10),'') +
           COALESCE(CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(@AddressLine2))>0 THEN
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(@AddressLine2)) END + char(13) + char(10),'') +
           COALESCE(CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(@AddressLine3))>0 THEN
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(@AddressLine3)) END + char(13) + char(10),'') +
           COALESCE(CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(@AddressLine4))>0 THEN
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(@AddressLine4)) END,''),'')
end
go
```